# How come this linked list isn't working?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm supposed to make a simple linked list in c++. Each node is supposed to contain a `char` value and an `int`. The user enters a letter and the info is stored in the linked list. When the user enters 0, it's supposed to output all of letters the user entered.

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct linkedlist
{
    linkedlist(char value, linkedlist* p = NULL)
    {
        next = p;
        this->value = value;
        this->input = value;
    }

    linkedlist(linkedlist* p = NULL)
    {
        next = p;
    }

    char input;
    int value;
    linkedlist* next;
};

void main()
{
    linkedlist* head = NULL;
    linkedlist* ptr = NULL;
    char input;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Enter a character: ";
        cin >> input;
        if (input == '0')
            break;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = new linkedlist(input);
            head->next = ptr; //points to the first one         
        }
        else
        {
            ptr = new linkedlist(input);
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    ptr = head; // Start at the beginning of the linked list
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout << ptr->input << endl;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

If I enter `r,s,t` it's only outputting the first letter `r`.
Thanks for all help :)

Comment: Probably because you have not debugged it.

Comment: When you enter a characer are you also hitting Enter?

Comment: Yes^, I press enter. I added each character like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `head` to point to the first element of the linked list, and `ptr` to point to the last element.

Your current code is this:

```
if (head == NULL)
{
        head = new linkedlist(input);
        head->next = ptr; //points to the first one         
}
```

This sets the head to be the first element, but then sets next to `NULL` (which it already is). What you want to do is

```
if (head == NULL)
{
    head = new linkedlist(input);
    ptr = head;
}
```

This creates the head and then sets `ptr` to that element (as at this point, `head` is also the last element of the linked list).

The next thing you do is this:

```
else
{
    ptr = new linkedlist(input);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

This sets `ptr` to a new element, but (as noted in the other answer) does not connect it to the rest of the list. What you want to do is

```
else
{
    ptr->next = new linkedlist(input);
    ptr = ptr->next;    
}
```

This sets the element *after* the current last element to the new input, the updates our pointer to the last element.

I do recommend that you review your code, as there are some other concerns. For one, you have a constructor and some parameters that you don't use. Also, technically the `linkedlist` struct is only a *node* of the linked list. If you want a single struct that functions as a full-fledged linked list, it needs to manage the head and tail pointers of its nodes.

Answer (score 3):

This code probably doesn't do what you want:

```
    ptr = new linkedlist(input);
    ptr = ptr->next;
```

This creates a new `linkedlist` node, but doesn't connect it to the linked list `head` in any way. This is the part of the code where you need to do something to connect it with your existing list.